# Execute query until timer reaches zero (PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, session, timer

I'm doing a module of rental videos, I've done the shopping cart but I only need to execute an update query if the user don't submit his order before within five minutes, I need a timer (I'm using PHP and MySQL) that is not reset when changing page, some like an $_SESSION, when user add a item in the cart his status on his table be "unavailable" (just to mention something) and the timer begins, and when it reaches zero do a update query and change his state to "available". What interests me most is getting the timer is maintained and not restart when changing page.

I need ideas from you, your suggestions are welcome, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You Can store the time-stamp into Mysql table when user adds item to cart, And then create function in a separate php file that checks for time stamps that are expired and updates the status of items that are having expired times,

Now You can either use 'Crons job' to auto check for expired timers or run that function on any user interaction with system as per your needs...!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly start session and store time stamp both in database and in session when user registers. Then write code that checks last request time is more than 5 mins by subtracting last time stamp with current time. If it's more than 5 mins then change state to available.

Also you can achieve this with MySQL triggers.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx